# How to unlink One2many Field values on onchange in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

> I created a module to add sale order lines as per customer to PO Order lines.

[Selecting customer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vd5l.jpg)

> When i add Sale Order it will be added in PO order.

[SO added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdhSj.jpg)

> I was trying to unlink a specific ids from one2many field. in picture Add SO fields

```
    class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit= "purchase.order"
    _name = "purchase.order"


    order_ids = fields.Many2many('sale.order', String="Add Order",domain="[('partner_id', 'child_of', partner_id),('state', 'in', ('quotation','socreated','done'))]")




    @api.onchange('order_ids')
    def orders_change(self):
        if not self.order_ids:
            return {}
        if not self.partner_customer_id:
            warning = {
                'title': _('Warning!'),
                'message': _('You must first select a partner!'),
            }
            # self.order_ids =False
            return {'warning': warning}

        line_ids = [] 

        u_ids=[]

        new_lines = self.env['purchase.order.line']


        for qt in self.order_ids:
            for i in self.order_line.mapped('sale_order_id'):

                line_ids.append(i)

            for u in self.order_ids:
                if u.id in line_id:
                    u_ids.append(u)
                    line_ids.remove(u)


            if line_ids and u_ids:
                lp = self.order_line.filtered(lambda r: r.sale_order_id <= line_ids[0])
                lp2 = self.order_line.filtered(lambda r: r.sale_order_id <= u_ids[0])


                for line in self.order_line:
                    if line in lp:
                        # self.order_line = [(6, 0, lp2.ids)]

                        line.unlink()

                continue



            for line in qt.order_line:
                # Load a PO line only once
                if line in self.order_line.mapped('sale_order_line_id'):
                    continue


                #seller section
                seller = line.product_id._select_seller(
                    line.product_id,
                    partner_id=self.partner_id,
                    quantity=line.product_uom_qty,
                    date=self.date_order and self.date_order[:10],
                    uom_id=line.product_uom)

                price_unit = self.env['account.tax']._fix_tax_included_price(seller.price,
                                                                             line.product_id.supplier_taxes_id,
                                                                             line.tax_id) if seller else 0.0
                if price_unit and seller and self.currency_id and seller.currency_id != self.currency_id:
                    price_unit = seller.currency_id.compute(price_unit, self.currency_id)

                if seller and line.product_uom and seller.product_uom != line.product_uom:
                    price_unit = self.env['product.uom']._compute_price(seller.product_uom.id, price_unit,
                                                                        to_uom_id=line.product_uom.id)
                unit = price_unit

                qty = line.product_uom_qty
                if float_compare(qty, 0.0, precision_rounding=line.product_uom.rounding) <= 0:
                    qty = 0.0
                tax_id = line.tax_id or line.product_id.taxes_id

                data = {
                    'sale_order_line_id': line.id,
                    'name': line.name,
                    'sequence_number':line.sequence_number,
                    'product_id': line.product_id.id,
                    'product_qty': qty,
                    'product_uom': line.product_id.uom_po_id or line.product_id.uom_id,
                    'price_unit': unit,
                    'cpo_no' : line.order_id.cpo_number,
                    'cpo_product_qty': qty,
                    'cpo_product_uom': line.product_id.uom_id,
                    'cpo_price_unit': line.price_unit,
                    'discount': 0.0,
                    'date_planned':(datetime.today() + relativedelta(weeks=4)).strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT),

                }
                new_line = new_lines.new(data)
                new_line._set_additional_fields(self)
                new_lines += new_line
        if new_lines :
            self.order_line += new_lines



class PurchaseOrderLine(models.Model):
    _inherit= "purchase.order.line"
    _name = "purchase.order.line"

    sale_order_line_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order.line', 'Order Line', ondelete='set null', select=True
                                        )

    sale_order_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order', related='sale_order_line_id.order_id', string='Order',
                                   store=False)
```

> When i remove a order_ids , i want to unlink related lines from order_line (po)

link_ids will hold order_ids when it selected, when a id removed from order_ids it will be removed from link_ids.
u_ids will hold the rest of order_id when it deleted.

when i remove a id from order_ids iwant to unlink the related line from order_line

but i cant delete it.

i have user [6,0,ids] method to replace values , it wont work in create state.
Please help me.

Comment: when you change the order_ids the lines of selected SO addes normaly but when you remove it the lines will not ?

Comment: yes . if i delete any added id from order_ids i want to remove its line from order_line

Comment: try to remove every record by using [(5,0,0)] then add the ids. this worked for me but the only problem is that it work if an other field trigger the onchange method not the same many2many or one2many field

Comment: but [(5,0,0)] won't work in create() right?

Comment: if you didn't find any solution why don't you use update button when he change the selected order ids he needs to validate before showing the one2many field and this way you will work on write always because create will happen when he validate the the choices. what i'm trying to say is find what it work and work arround it to find a way to use it

Comment: Thanks Charif . Let me try it.

Comment: post your answer if it work we need it too good luck

Answer (score 2):

```
new_lines = self.env['purchase.order.line']
        for qt in self.order_ids:
            for i in self.order_line.mapped('sale_order_id'):
                line_id.append(i.id)
                line_ids.append(i)
            for u in self.order_ids:
                if u.id in line_id:
                    u_id.append(u.id)
                    line_id.remove(u.id)
                    u_ids.append(u)
                    line_ids.remove(u)
            k = self.order_line.mapped('sale_order_id')
            if line_id and line_ids and u_ids:
                lp = self.order_line.filtered(lambda r: r.sale_order_id <= line_ids[0])
                lp6 = self.order_line.filtered(lambda r: r.sale_order_id not in line_ids)
                lp2 = self.order_line.filtered(lambda r: r.sale_order_id in u_ids)

                for line in self.order_line:
                    if line in lp:
                        self.update({
                            'order_line': [(5, _, _)],
                        })
                for o in lp6:
                    data = {
                        'sale_order_line_id': o.sale_order_line_id.id,
                        'name': o.name,
                        'sequence_number': o.sequence_number,
                        'product_id': o.product_id.id,
                        'product_qty': o.product_qty,
                        'product_uom': o.product_uom,
                        'price_unit': o.price_unit,
                        'cpo_no': o.cpo_no,
                        'cpo_product_qty': o.cpo_product_qty,
                        'cpo_product_uom': o.cpo_product_uom,
                        'cpo_price_unit': o.cpo_price_unit,
                        # 'quote_ref':line.order_id.origin,
                        'discount': 0.0,
                        'date_planned': (datetime.today() + relativedelta(weeks=4)).strftime(
                            DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT),
                    }
                    for line in qt.order_line:
                                # Load a PO line only once
                        if line in self.order_line.mapped('sale_order_line_id'):
                            continue
                    new_line = new_lines.new(data)
                    new_line._set_additional_fields(self)
                    new_lines += new_line



                    new_line = False

                continue
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry i'm late it's been a log time:

try to remove every record by using `[(5,0,0)]` then add the ids. this worked for me but the only problem is that it work if an other field trigger the onchange method not the same many2many or one2many field

but in create mode if you didn't find any solution why don't you use update button when he change the selected order ids he needs to validate before showing the one2many field and this way you will work on write always because create will happen when he validate the the choices. what i'm trying to say is find what it work and work arround it to find a way to use it

Comment: yes i have used [5,_,_] to remove all data and the problem i faced in create was solved by : - when i remove an sale order id from many2many i will filter the lines which not contain that sale_order_id and use the new_line add method to rewrite the lines.

Comment: lp6 = self.order_line.filtered(lambda r: r.sale_order_id not in line_ids)

Comment: post you answer if you could we want to see your work

Answer (score 0):

For the field you used to make relation:-

```
sale_order_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order', related='sale_order_line_id.order_id', string='Order',
                               store=False)
```

please try to give attribute ondelete = 'cascade' and change the line as :-

```
sale_order_id = fields.Many2one('sale.order', related='sale_order_line_id.order_id', string='Order', ondelete ='cascade'
                               store=False)
```

If you put like this , when the related sale order is deleted the one2many entry with relation record will be also removed. This is just an example and you could try this way.
Thanks

Comment: it won't work, actually am deleting order_ids [many2many] from purcahse order and i want to delete the respective order id from po line

Answer (score 0):

Following is a common logic for deleting a record in one2many

```
@api.onchage('field_name')
def onchange_field_name(self):
  for line in self.one2many_field_records:
    if line.order_id == 'your_satisfying_condition':
        line.unlink()
```

This is the usual way to delete the order line records

Comment: This delete all form view data, like reset.